# Dynamic Grouped Table Cells

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

In my storyboard, I have a UITableView and it has the following Properties

```
Style: Grouped
Content: Dynamic Prototypes
```

My question was how to make the different groups. When I run the app right now, there is no white backing (Only the default lined backing) with the text placed on top. Also, if I then created these dynamic groups, how would I set their header and footer?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {
        return 2;

    }
    -(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

        // implement your code

    }
    -(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{

        //implement your code
    }
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

     /// Write basic code//

switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0:
//It belongs to  first group and implement your code.
               break;
        case 1:
//It belongs to second group and implement your code.
               break;


}
```

I think it will be helpful to you

Comment: How do I put individual items in each group? Right now with the code row.item == 0 All of the groups get the item.

Comment: Also, the white is not appearing behind the items.

Comment: implement '- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath' method and Use indexPath.section.

Comment: Don't worry, I fixed the colour issue but how do I get the items to only go in some groups?

Comment: I have edited my code and implement your code in two cases what you want.